# What does MongoDB findAndModify do with fields that are in the old document, but not the updated document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

If I call [findAndModify](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify), and a document matches the **query**, but the existing document has fields that the **doc** does not, will the old fields still exist in the new document, or will  they be removed?

I've checked the [findAndModify docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) and the answers's not obvious. Trying it, fields in the old doc that aren't in the new doc seem to be removed - since this involves losing data, and there's nothing explicit about this is the docs, I'm not sure if this is the expected behaviour or not.

Comment: You need to use `$set: {new_field: "new_value"}` to add a new field to an existing document. Exactly the same behaviour as `db.collection.update()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) behaves exactly like [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update). This means that the document in the database will be completely replaced by the document you provide, unless you use operators like [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) or [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) which explicitely modify a document.

By the way: When the node.js-specific documentation is too brief, the description of the analogue command in [the general manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) is often much more detailed.

Comment: Dammit beat me to it. +1

Comment: Thanks @Philipp, not only for the answer but for the docs tip too.